# What WCF Exceptions should I retry on failure for? (such as the bogus 'xxx host did not receive a reply within 00:01:00')

Tags: wcf, exception, timeout, fault

I have a WCF client that has thrown this common error, just to be resolved with retrying the HTTP call to the server.  For what it's worth this exception was not generated within 1 minute.  It was generated in 3 seconds.

> The request operation sent to xxxxxx
>   did not receive a reply within the
>   configured timeout (00:01:00). The
>   time allotted to this operation may
>   have been a portion of a longer
>   timeout. This may be because the
>   service is still processing the
>   operation or because the service was
>   unable to send a reply message. Please
>   consider increasing the operation
>   timeout (by casting the channel/proxy
>   to IContextChannel  and setting the
>   OperationTimeout property) and ensure
>   that the service is able to connect to
>   the client

How are professionals handling these common WCF errors?  What other bogus errors should I handle.

For example, I'm considering timing the WCF call and if that above (bogus) error is thrown in under 55 seconds, I retry the entire operation (using a while() loop).  I believe I have to reset the entire channel, but I'm hoping you guys will tell me what's right to do.

What other

Comment: I suggest you ask a separate question on why your 1 minute timeout times out after 3 seconds. That's not actually the way it's meant to work.

Comment: @John: It only occasionaly does that while I'm developing and waiting for my Azure Fabric to start up.  I'm guessing that this is a retryable error, and most of my code is based entirely on the WCF samples.

Comment: the Azure factor a pretty good reason to ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

I make all of my WCF calls from a custom "using" statement which handles exceptions and potential retires. My code optionally allows me to pass a policy object to the statement so I can easily change the behavior, like if I don't want to retry on error.

The gist of the code is as follows:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public static void ProxyUsing<T>(ClientBase<T> proxy, Action action)
    where T : class
{
    try
    {
        proxy.Open();
        using(OperationContextScope context = new OperationContextScope(proxy.InnerChannel))
        {
          //Add some headers here, or whatever you want
            action();
        }
    }
    catch(FaultException fe)
    {
      //Handle stuff here
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if(proxy != null
                && proxy.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
            {
                proxy.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                proxy.Abort();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            if(proxy != null)
            {
                proxy.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use the call like follows:

```
ProxyUsing<IMyService>(myService = GetServiceInstance(), () =>
{
    myService.SomeMethod(...);
});
```

The NoInlining call probably isn't important for you. I need it because I have some custom logging code that logs the call stack after an exception, so it's important to preserve that method hierarchy in that case.

Comment: This is helpful, although Im hoping to learn what exceptions are worthy of catching and what circumstances they are worth it